# Columnwise matrix multiplication of matrices stored inside lists in R?

Tags: r, list, apply, matrix-multiplication

I have two large datasets stored in lists (L1, L2) with same dimensions. In each list element L[[.]], there's a data frame.  I want to multiply both lists column-wise, and then some the results for all combinations of L1[[i]] . L2[[j]] for whatever value *i* and *j* may take.

For some clarification, see the code below

```
#Data Generation-----------------------
set.seed(200)
a = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
b = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
c = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
d = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)

#Creating index and binding------------
r = cbind(rep(1,4),a)
s = cbind(rep(2,4),b)
o = as.data.frame(rbind(r,s))
t = cbind(rep(1,4),c)
u = cbind(rep(2,4),d)
p = as.data.frame(rbind(t,u))

#Splitting the data -------------------
list.1 = split(o, o$V1) #o$V1 is the index column
list.2 = split(p, p$V1) #o$V1 is the index column
```

Now, I want to reproduce in R the Excel function SUMPRODUCT.

So, for instance, from the data above, I want a simple data frame as in:

```
#Col1      #Col2
sum(a*c)   sum(b*c)
sum(a*d)   sum(b*d)
```

The problem is that *a*,*b*,*c*, and *d* are all inside lists now. I had a go at it with *for-loops*, but to no avail. I tried to use the *split-apply-combine* approach, but I wasn't successful either.

> Since both lists have 9000 elements each, I'm looking for an optimized
>   way to do this. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Expanding the example for 3 elements in each list as asked by userR

```
#Data Generation-----------------------
set.seed(200)
a = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
b = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
c = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
d = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
e = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
f = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)

#Creating index and binding------------
r = cbind(rep(1,4),a)
s = cbind(rep(2,4),b)
m = cbind(rep(3,4),c)
o = as.data.frame(rbind(r,s,m))

t = cbind(rep(1,4),d)
u = cbind(rep(2,4),e)
v = cbind(rep(3,4),f)
p = as.data.frame(rbind(t,u,v))

#Splitting the data -------------------
list.1 = split(o, o$V1) #o$V1 is the index column
list.2 = split(p, p$V1) #o$V1 is the index column
```

Now every list has 3 elements each containing a 4x4 matrix.

The result I'm looking for is structured as:

```
#Col1      #Col2      #Col3
sum(a*d)   sum(b*d)   sum(c*d)
sum(a*e)   sum(b*e)   sum(c*e)
sum(a*f)   sum(b*f)   sum(c*f)
```

For my real problem, the result will be an array (matrix or dataframe) with 9000 columns and 9000 rows.

---

Edit: Adding real data as recommended by userR

useR suggested I showed some real data so people will know how my real data look like:

`dput(list.1[1:3])`

```
list(`1` = structure(list(vol = c(1425.76, 272.52, 0, 0, 31912.78, 
6056.18, 8212.88, 3909.3, 0, 761.06, 22.45, 237.18), i_1 = c(2819.81, 
4026.72, 827.2, 4790.52, 12218.1, 3632.64, 6308.66, 4076.71, 
2192.98, 952.94, 112.84, 170.97), i_2 = c(2857.88, 2914.34, 761.87, 
4412.4, 11046.36, 2363.24, 7761.31, 5431.03, 1337.62, 857, 103.46, 
110.33), i_3 = c(1389.12, 932.86, 238.51, 5046, 5298.57, 3087.9, 
8746.02, 7129.57, 708.53, 549.1, 86.58, 163.15), i_4 = c(1626.96, 
936.04, 377.81, 4909.62, 6323.5, 2766.49, 3746.06, 2858.07, 900.29, 
975.21, 102.76, 295.1), i_5 = c(1653.05, 1724.74, 321.59, 3937.2, 
6966.48, 2614.67, 3326.99, 2371.44, 1082.43, 970.25, 123.51, 
491.92), i_6 = c(1584.14, 3399.31, 392.24, 3957.88, 8042.5, 2614.46, 
2371.67, 1896.1, 1201.83, 1314.06, 161.23, 892.91)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(vol = c(10774.34, 
287.53, 0, 0, 57507.79, 10692.91, 9028.38, 10355.78, 8900.38, 
3253.59, 22.45, 219), i_1 = c(5760.16, 4315.77, 585.28, 2886.11, 
23767.55, 3095.39, 6705.94, 6445.96, 10612.49, 2470.32, 126.65, 
143.46), i_2 = c(5035.23, 1785.77, 405.05, 4492.64, 21509.39, 
3654.16, 10203.03, 9505.1, 6628.42, 1298.06, 111.76, 110.13), 
    i_3 = c(2798.54, 1920.72, 464.92, 7916.61, 13628.15, 8365.88, 
    18425.9, 22368.93, 2253.38, 1078.65, 101.34, 134.98), i_4 = c(2344.65, 
    1407.02, 369.7, 2889.69, 7618.72, 2110.01, 4982.27, 2250.94, 
    1744.4, 1033.89, 105.74, 212.26), i_5 = c(1653.05, 1724.74, 
    321.59, 3937.2, 6966.48, 2614.67, 3326.99, 2371.44, 1082.43, 
    970.25, 123.51, 491.92), i_6 = c(1584.14, 3399.31, 392.24, 
    3957.88, 8042.5, 2614.46, 2371.67, 1896.1, 1201.83, 1314.06, 
    161.23, 892.91)), row.names = 13:24, class = "data.frame"), 
    `3` = structure(list(vol = c(850.15, 218.58, 0, 0, 38959.27, 
    3081.31, 3441.35, 2760.54, 0, 2826.8, 0, 34.12), i_1 = c(6048.28, 
    3545.14, 1566.05, 2866.46, 20149.24, 1459.03, 2051.68, 2047.74, 
    5059.57, 3369.86, 129.37, 361.49), i_2 = c(1728.12, 1530.14, 
    364.37, 4761.97, 6934.24, 1802.96, 5394.15, 3972.96, 510.25, 
    989.3, 109.05, 322.37), i_3 = c(1182.59, 750.55, 311.19, 
    5540.96, 4544.96, 2535.07, 8926.35, 7209.61, 423.66, 446.62, 
    92.21, 282.36), i_4 = c(1179.1, 645.18, 283.97, 4616.66, 
    5063.41, 3110.14, 9240.41, 4752.86, 744.85, 648.44, 100.52, 
    311.67), i_5 = c(1653.05, 1724.74, 321.59, 3937.2, 6966.48, 
    2614.67, 3326.99, 2371.44, 1082.43, 970.25, 123.51, 491.92
    ), i_6 = c(1584.14, 3399.31, 392.24, 3957.88, 8042.5, 2614.46, 
    2371.67, 1896.1, 1201.83, 1314.06, 161.23, 892.91)), row.names = 25:36, class = "data.frame"))
```

`dput(list.2[1:3])`

```
list(`1` = structure(list(Index = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), itenm1 = c(998399, 998399, 998399, 998399,  998399,
998399, 998399, 998399, 998399, 998399, 998399, 998399 ), j_1 =
c(-261.62831, -605.82802, -190.35225, -802.27542, -835.07636, 
-709.70814, -444.26492, -207.96871, -986.93606, -968.29324, -7675.97567, 
-1271.43424), j_2 = c(0, -188.67302, 0, -799.17034, 0, 247.70379,  0, 0, 1051.71715, -27.94787, 0, -13.34628), j_3 = c(0, 0, 0,  0, 0,
-207.58736, 0, 0, -2333.43115, -1346.57579, 0, -205.13053 ), j_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), j_5 = c(0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), j_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0)),
row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `2` = structure(list(Index = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), itenm1 = c(998398, 998398, 998398, 998398, 
    998398, 998398, 998398, 998398, 998398, 998398, 998398, 998398
    ), j_1 = c(-106.64606, -203.78915, -76.30121, -310.10454, 
    -321.62536, -227.3462, -160.82221, -70.87354, -286.94001, 
    -137.28382, -3779.42484, -604.71574), j_2 = c(0, -96.94433, 
   0, -297.21757, 0, 67.67053, 0, 0, 309.38773, -8.42931, 0, 
   -6.7299), j_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -56.71107, 0, 0, -686.43453, 
   -406.13843, 0, -103.43761), j_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0), j_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0), j_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 13:24, class = "data.frame"), 
   `3` = structure(list(Index = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), itenm1 = c(998397, 998397, 998397, 998397, 
   998397, 998397, 998397, 998397, 998397, 998397, 998397, 998397
   ), j_1 = c(-238.10472, -543.97414, -71.04739, -756.58841, 
   -782.7918, -667.84871, -424.38314, -193.82405, -638.12855, 
   -319.65804, -6693.88425, -1189.81911), j_2 = c(0, -182.11783, 
   0, -750.99738, 0, 233.80836, 0, 0, 683.61007, -18.48993, 
   0, -11.46144), j_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -195.94234, 0, 0, -1516.71678, 
   -890.87644, 0, -176.16082), j_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0), j_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0), j_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 25:36, class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hello, userR. First of all, thanks a lot. I'm testing the options you gave me. It may take some time since I'm not a speedy coder and take my time to understand each line. Right now, I'm testing sumprod_mapply. Since the real dimensions of my lists are diferent, I'm tying to understand what every number means in the line with the `rep` command. If it works out, I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: To your first question, yes. I will only have two lists, but inside every element of my list there's a matrix. Each list has 9000 elements, so they both have 9000 matrices. I want to multiply every possible combination of matrices from (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)... (9000,1)...(9000,9000). My output is expected to have 9000 rows and 9000 coluns. Thinking of column #s as the index of the elements of the first matrix, each column M will have 9000 rows, that represents `sum(M[#]*N[#]`, where N[#] is the element group of list 2.

Comment: Maybe this not-very-polished figure will help understand the idea I have in mind. https://imgur.com/a/DGRUmlM

Comment: See if my updated solution matches your expected output and whether it works for your real problem. The Rcpp method should be the fastest.

Comment: Dear useR, thanks again for the answer. I was out of office for a few days, but I'll review your answer as soon as I get Rcpp to work. I'm having some trouble with it now. When I solve it, I'll run your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: One immediate problem I see with your real data is that the matrices are not square (nxn). You can't multiply two matrices if the number of rows in the first one is not equal to the number of columns in the second. Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly, but if you want to implement my functions, you have to have either all square matrices (which was what you originally provided) or your first list has matrices all with mxn dimension while your second list has matrices all with nxp dimension.

Comment: Hey, useR, the matrices aren't square. The example given was with square matrices, but as I'm looking for a column-wise multiplication, dimensions shouldn't matter. This is why I used my example with sum(a*d) , instead of sum(a%*%d)

Answer (score 1):

Below I propose three methods and their benchmarks: `mapply`, nested `for` loops, and with `RcppArmadillo`.

**Data:**

```
#Data Generation-----------------------
set.seed(200)
a = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
b = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
c = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
d = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
e = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)
f = matrix(sample(50,16), 4)

#Creating index and binding------------
r = cbind(rep(1,4),a)
s = cbind(rep(2,4),b)
m = cbind(rep(3,4),c)
o = as.data.frame(rbind(r,s,m))

t = cbind(rep(1,4),d)
u = cbind(rep(2,4),e)
v = cbind(rep(3,4),f)
p = as.data.frame(rbind(t,u,v))

#Splitting the data -------------------
list.1 = split(o[,-1], o$V1) #o$V1 is the index column
list.2 = split(p[,-1], p$V1) #o$V1 is the index column

list.1 = lapply(list.1, as.matrix)
list.2 = lapply(list.2, as.matrix)
```

Here, I'm cheating a little bit by first removing the id column and converting each element of `list.1` and `list.2` to matrices. Doing so improves our function's performance.

**Initialize functions:**

```
# Rcpp -----------------------------------------------
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)

cppFunction(depends = "RcppArmadillo",
"arma::mat sumprod_Rcpp(List x, List y){
  List xlist(x);
  List ylist(y);
  int n = xlist.size();
  arma::mat m(n,n);

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
      arma::mat xMat = xlist[i];
      arma::mat yMat = ylist[j];
      arma::vec v = arma::vectorise(xMat*yMat);
      m(j,i) = sum(v);
    }
  }
  return(m);
}
"
)

# Nested For -----------------------------------------
sumprod_for <- function(x, y){
  mat <- matrix(NA,length(list.1),length(list.1))

  for(i in 1:length(list.1)){
    for(j in 1:length(list.1)){
      mat[j,i] <- sum(x[[i]] %*% y[[j]])
    }
  }
  return(mat)
}

# Mapply ---------------------------------------------
sumprod_mapply <- function(x, y){
  matrix(mapply(function(j, k){
    sum(x[[j]] %*% y[[k]])
  }, 
  rep(1:length(list.1), each = length(list.1)), 
  rep(1:length(list.1), length(list.1))
  ), 
  length(list.1), 
  length(list.1)
  )
}  

# Ryan's sapply --------------------------------------
sumprod_sapply <- function(x, y){
  sapply(x, function(j){
    lapply(y, function(k) sum(j %*% k))
  })
}
```

**Check if outputs are identical:**

```
identical(sumprod_mapply(list.1, list.2), matrix(unlist(sumprod_sapply(list.1, list.2)), length(list.1), length(list.1)))
# [1] TRUE
identical(sumprod_mapply(list.1, list.2), sumprod_for(list.1, list.2))
# [1] TRUE
identical(sumprod_mapply(list.1, list.2), sumprod_Rcpp(list.1, list.2))
# [1] TRUE

sumprod_Rcpp(list.1, list.2)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] 44882 40505 49670
# [2,] 29750 26897 32260
# [3,] 45898 41248 50847

sumprod_for(list.1, list.2)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] 44882 40505 49670
# [2,] 29750 26897 32260
# [3,] 45898 41248 50847

sumprod_mapply(list.1, list.2)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] 44882 40505 49670
# [2,] 29750 26897 32260
# [3,] 45898 41248 50847

sumprod_sapply(list.1, list.2)
#   1     2     3    
# 1 44882 40505 49670
# 2 29750 26897 32260
# 3 45898 41248 50847
```

**Benchmarking:**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sumprod_mapply(list.1, list.2), 
               sumprod_sapply(list.1, list.2),
               sumprod_for(list.1, list.2),
               sumprod_Rcpp(list.1, list.2),
               times = 10000L)
```

**Results:**

```
Unit: microseconds
                           expr    min     lq      mean median     uq      max neval
 sumprod_mapply(list.1, list.2) 34.345 39.082 51.274501 41.846 62.373 2448.292 10000
 sumprod_sapply(list.1, list.2) 37.108 42.635 56.119414 45.398 67.504 2324.733 10000
    sumprod_for(list.1, list.2) 10.264 13.422 17.685540 15.001 22.502  120.008 10000
   sumprod_Rcpp(list.1, list.2)  2.369  3.948  5.247494  4.738  6.317   88.032 10000
```

You can't go wrong with `Rcpp` implementation when looking for performance gain. Surprisingly though, `sumprod_for` is much faster than `sumprod_mapply` and `sumprod_sapply` probably due to `mapply` implicitly coercing the list output to vector. Feel free to propose more solutions, and I will add them to the benchmarks.

Comment: Hello, useR. Thanks for your answer. In my real case, my lists have 9000 elements each, and each element is a matrix. I'd like to ask for further clarification about line `rep(1:2, each = 2), rep(1:2, 2)), 2, 2)`. I assume both `rep` commands are there so you have (1,1,2,2) twice, and then you can combine it as (1,1)(1,2),(2,1),(2,2). But what are is `2, 2)` for? How would this function be if it were written for lists my original ones?

Comment: @userR, I just added an expanded example with 3 matrices per list, each matrix in an element

Comment: `sapply(list.1, function(x) lapply(list.2, function(y) sum(x %*% y)))` gives the same results, although it's probably slower than the for-loop.

Comment: I moved away from the Rcpp piece of code for now and went to try the for-loop. After trying to run it, an error occurs. `Error in x[[i]] %*% y[[j]] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`. I tried to `as.matrix()` `x` and `y` but it didn't work.

Comment: @MasonBeau Did you convert the elements to matrices and remove the indicator variable like I did in my answer? Particularly `list.1 = split(o[,-1], o$V1); list.2 = split(p[,-1], p$V1); list.1 = lapply(list.1, as.matrix); list.2 = lapply(list.2, as.matrix)`. My functions would not work if your elements are dataframes or if they are not nXm * mXn.

Comment: I just got drowned in all this code. I'll try to figure things out and will get back to you.

Comment: @MasonBeau The "Check if outputs are identical" and "Benchmarking" sections are really irrelevant to actually getting the code to run. All you have to do is convert your elements to matrices, and remove the first column, run the entire "Initialize functions" section (`install.packages("Rcpp"); install.packages("RcppArmadillo")` if you need to) then run `sumprod_Rcpp(list.1, list.2)` to use the functions.

Comment: Guys, I'm grateful to all the help, but unfortunately, none of the pieces above worked for me so far. I'm sure I'm making mistakes with data type for `sumprod`, and I have had a lot of difficulties with Rcpp. I'll work on it for a few more days. If I can't get it right by then, I might choose the answer as right anyway. Again, thank you.

Comment: @MasonBeau Well, without telling us what difficulties you had or what errors you received, it's very difficult for us to help you. Also, if all solutions are not working for your real data, perhaps you need to provide a sample that is more representative of your actual data. Could you maybe provide just the first three elements of your two actual lists? Something like: `list_short1 <- list1[1:3]` and `list_short2 <- list2[1:3]`

Comment: Hello, useR. Right now, my error for the sumprod is `Error in x[[i]] %*% y[[j]] :requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`. It's clear my data is not converted to the right type. I have tried to convert the elements of my list to matrix, but so far, to no avail.

Comment: A snapshot of my list.1 is here: https://imgur.com/vOfBJp5 
List.2 is similar, only with different numbers.

Comment: @MasonBeau Instead of a snapshot, can you provide the data itself in your question body? Just type `dput(list.1[1:3])` and `dput(list.2[1:3])` in your R console and copy and paste (exactly) the output of those commands into your question.

Comment: Hey, useR, I adapted your command into dput(list.1[1:1]), because (a) the result wouldn't fit in here, and (b) because the elements are actually pretty similar in magnitude of its numbers

Comment: @MasonBeau Please delete these comments and post them again in your **question body**. This information should be included in your question itself in the first place.